# Perl SDL Windows Installation

Tags: windows, perl, download, installation, sdl

I'm using Windows and I need the SDL Library to start using SDL with Perl. I've been pointed to http://www.libsdl.org/ to download it. My first queston is, which library do I want from that page? There's 3 to choose from...

Then I've been pointed to 4 other SDL extensions by this page: http://arstechnica.com/gaming/news/2006/02/games-perl.ars. From those I've found there's a normal Win32 version and also a devel one. Which do I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I went on the SDL IRC chat. Seems the best way to do it is not to install SDL, but to install the Perl module Alien::SDL.